# Prove that 4 points in the hexagon satisfy given conditions

Tags: combinatorics

In a regular hexagon with a distance $ 1 $ between the parallel sides $4$ points have been thrown. Prove that at least two of these points are located at a distance of not more than $0.87$.

I've tried to prove from the contrary. Assume that all $4$ points are locating on the distance more than $0.87$. Then they are located in the vertices of square with the length of the side $0.87$. The diagonals of this square are $\approx 1.23$. But the length of the longest part of hexagon is $\approx 1.154$ (diameter of circumcircle of hexagon). So it is impossible to place square in hexagon in such way that all vertices would be inside the hexagon.

Am I right in  my conclusions? I will be grateful if you tell me if there is another way to prove this statement

Comment: You probably mean "Prove that *at least* two of these points are ..."

Comment: Yes, it's my mistake. I've edit question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Divide the hexagon in three equal diamond shaped pentagonal parts by drawing three "spokes" from the center of the hexagon to the center of three sides.  The diameter of each diamond is $\tfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ and there must be one that contains at least two of the four points.

Comment: Thank you! This solution leaves no questions.